# remove widgets in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, widgets

In home page you can see "BEST sELLER " & "ON SALE"

Please help me to remove those. Those are widgets in galagiftshop theme.

I changed widget from "ALL store views" to "Pinkview".

So Products which were under BEST sELLER  & ON SALE are removed. BUt those

"BEST sELLER  & ON SALE" text are still displaying in other "store views".

Please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: there are two possibilty one in xml file and another is in CMS page Home in xml tag

Comment: Also possibility like this is custom them so they provide you option in back end system configuration.

Comment: there are 2 xml files , one is em_sliderwidget.xml and cms.xml, in both i did't found any words related to "bestseller" and "onsale". in system>configuratin, also I checked, it was not there....

Comment: check on phtml file like and also search in project this two words

Comment: enable template path hint so you got which file you are calling

Comment: hi, please visit the link now : http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/ what i have to do now?

Comment: you can find emtabs.xml file and hear you can find the tab

Comment: form this u can remove the tab.....also check in /template/emtabs/group.phtml file

Comment: this is emtabs/group.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/wwPfL5xY please help me what i have to do in code?

Comment: also upload the xml file

Comment: this is cms.xml file http://pastebin.com/kJWSbMRF  . let me know if you need any other files....

Comment: I need emtabs.xml this file

Comment: emtabs.xml  = > http://pastebin.com/zFp7MsTL

Comment: in widget disable widget form magento and then change

Comment: hi, i am sorry, I did't got what to do, can you please explain me clearly, is  i have to edit the code in emtabs.xml or what i have to do?

Comment: i deleted widgets, it did't worked.

Comment: there is some other configuration in backend

Comment: okay, i checked once, i will check again clearly....

Comment: I installed that site, 2 times. please visit this :

http://schoolboards3.newtrendzonline.com/ 

admin username : admin

admin password : schoolboards

you can disable "best seller" and  "on sale" here.

thanks in advance

Comment: you can manage content form Widget "Gala Rainbow Home Tabs"

Comment: it solved here : http://schoolboards3.newtrendzonline.com/ , you are a genius. thanks a lot.... write your answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at 3 place.

1. In `emtabs.xml` File.
2. Gala Theme Configuration.
3. Or You have edit the widget `Gala Rainbow Home Tabs`.

Let me know if any question.